# How to load additional JARs for an Hadoop Streaming job on Amazon EMR

Tags: python, hadoop, jar, streaming, amazon-emr

**TL;DR**

*How I can upload or specify additional JARs to an Hadoop Streaming Job on Amazon Elastic MapReduce (Amazon EMR)?*

**Long version**

I want to analyze a set of [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/) files (> 2000 files) using Hadoop on Amazon Elastic MapReduce (Amazon EMR). It should be a simple exercise through which I should gain some confidence with MapReduce and Amazon EMR (I am new to both).

Since python is my favorite language I have decided to use [Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/HadoopStreaming.html). I have built a simple mapper and reducer in python, and I have tested it on a local Hadoop (single node install). The command I was issuing on my local Hadoop install was this:

```
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.4.0-amzn-1.jar \
                  -files avro-1.7.7.jar,avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar \
                  -libjars avro-1.7.7.jar,avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar \
                  -input "input" \
                  -mapper "python2.7 $PWD/mapper.py"  \
                  -reducer "python2.7 $PWD/reducer.py" \
                  -output "output/outdir" \
                  -inputformat org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroAsTextInputFormat
```

and the job completed successfully.

I have a bucket on Amazon S3 with a folder containing all the input files and another folder with the mapper and reducer scripts (`mapper.py` and `reducer.py` respectively).

Using the interface I have created a small cluster, then I have added a [bootstrap action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/CLI_CreateStreaming.html) to install all the required python modules on each node and then I have added an ["Hadoop Streaming" step](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/CLI_CreateStreaming.html) specifying the location of the mapper and reducer scripts on S3.

The problem is that I don't have the slightest idea on *how I can upload or specify in the options the two JARs - `avro-1.7.7.jar` and `avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar` - required to run this job?*

I have tried several things:

- using the `-files` flag in combination with `-libjars` in the optional arguments;
- adding another bootstrap action that downloads the JARs on every node (and I have tried to download it on different locations on the nodes);
- I have tried to upload the JARs on my bucket and specify a full `s3://...` path as argument to `-libjars` (note: these file are actively ignored by Hadoop, and a warning is issued) in the options;

If I don't pass the two JARs the job fails (it does not recognize the `-inputformat` class), but I have tried all the possibilities (and combinations thereof!) I could think of to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I figures it out (and it was, of course, obvious):

Here's how I have done it:

1. add a bootstrap action that downloads the JARs on every node, for example you can upload the JARs in your bucket, make them public and then do:

   ```
   wget https://yourbucket/path/somejar.jar -O $HOME/somejar.jar
   wget https://yourbucket/path/avro-1.7.7.jar -O $HOME/avro-1.7.7.jar
   wget https://yourbucket/path/avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar -O $HOME/avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar
   ```
2. when you specify `-libjars` in the optional arguments *use the **abosolute** path*, so:

   ```
   -libjars /home/hadoop/somejar.jar,$HOME/avro-1.7.7.jar,/home/hadoop/avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar
   ```

I have lost a number of hours that I am ashamed to say, hope this helps somebody else.

**Edit (Feb 10th, 2015)**

I have double checked, and I want to point out that it seems that environment variable are not expanded when passed to the optional arguments field. So, use the explicit $HOME path (i.e. `/home/hadoop`)

**Edit (Feb 11th, 2015)**

If you want to launch the a streaming job on Amazon EMR using the AWS cli you can use the following command.

```
aws emr create-cluster  --ami-version '3.3.2' \
                        --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType='m1.medium' InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType='m3.xlarge' \
                        --name 'TestStreamingJob' \
                        --no-auto-terminate \
                        --log-uri 's3://path/to/your/bucket/logs/' \
                        --no-termination-protected \
                        --enable-debugging \
                        --bootstrap-actions Path='s3://path/to/your/bucket/script.sh',Name='ExampleBootstrapScript' Path='s3://path/to/your/bucket/another_script.sh',Name='AnotherExample' \
                        --steps file://./steps_test.json
```

and you can specify the steps in a JSON file:

```
[
 {
  "Name": "Avro",
  "Args": ["-files","s3://path/to/your/mapper.py,s3://path/to/your/reducer.py","-libjars","/home/hadoop/avro-1.7.7.jar,/home/hadoop/avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar","-inputformat","org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroAsTextInputFormat","-mapper","mapper.py","-reducer","reducer.py","-input","s3://path/to/your/input_directory/","-output","s3://path/to/your/output_directory/"],
  "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
  "Type": "STREAMING"
 }
]
```

(please note that the [official Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/CLI_CreateStreaming.html) is somewhat outdated, in fact it uses the old Amazon EMR CLI tool which is [deprecated](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-cli-install.html) in favor of the more recente [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/))